# Simple way to apply a rule (from list of rules) based on the presence of the a rule key within a string

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

If I have some strings eg:

```
str1 = "12-26b-14a";
str2 = "12-21h-14";
```

and I want to replace the string with a value based on the following rules:

```
testru = {"12-26b" -> xx, "12-21h" -> yy, "12-42e" -> zz};
```

I can make the following criteria:

```
DeleteCases[
             ReplaceAll[If[StringMatchQ[str1, # ~~ __], #] & /@ 
              Keys@testru, testru],
            Null][[1]]
```

> xx

```
DeleteCases[
             ReplaceAll[If[StringMatchQ[str2, # ~~ __], #] & /@ 
              Keys@testru, testru],
            Null][[1]]
```

> yy

This works, but I suspect there are much simpler/ more elegant ways to perform such a seemingly simple task.

In particular, `ReplaceAll` feels like overkill for a single element!

Any suggestions for an improved method?

### EDIT

I'd rather not mess with the structure of `testru` since I use this list for other purposes.

Also the strings do not have definite lengths so clipping the string by a certain number of characters is not viable.

Comment: "strings do not have definite lengths" - but if the prefixes are fixed, then Carl's use of `StringStartsQ[]` for matching suffices.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay., Yes, it would be a good solution (+1 vote). I added the second 'edit' comment to head off other answers based on fixed length strings.

Comment: Into what do you want `str1` and `str2` to transform?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
Replace[
    {str1, str2},
    {_?(StringStartsQ["12-26b"])->xx, _?(StringStartsQ["12-21h"])->yy},
    {1}
]
```

> {xx, yy}

**Addendum to address OP edits**

If you need to use `testru` as is, then you could do something like:

```
Replace[
    {str1, str2},
    Replace[testru, Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[PatternTest[Blank[], StringStartsQ[a]], b], {1}],
    {1}
]
```

> {xx, yy}

Answer (score 1):

```
rule = MapAt[_String?(StringStartsQ[#]) &, testru, {All, 1}]

Replace[ {str1, str2}, rule, All]
```

> {xx, yy}

```
{str1, str2} /. rule
```

> {xx, yy}

Also

```
srule = # ~~ ___ -> #2 & @@@ testru;

# & @@@ StringReplace[srule] @ {str1, str2}
```

> {xx, yy}